# Do the peer-reviewers in a submitted (journal) paper see each other comments?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Do the peer-reviewers in a submitted (journal) paper see each others comments? I mean it is obvious that if there are many reviewers in a submitted paper and make the same comments to the authors, what's the point? So, is there any case that the reviewers know each other co-reviewers' comments provided to the authors?

Comment: I multiple reviewers make similar points *independently* (as I think is the norm), then that is a valuable piece of information. Often enough, reviews will have quite little intersection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will likely vary by journal.

I think it's quite common that reviewers see each others' comments, typically at the stage where authors submit a revision with an accompanying discussion of the reviews and how they responded to them in the revision. Sometimes, depending on the journal, you get to see the other reviews already when the editor sends out the initial reviews and decision.

Note that the original and subsequent reviews are usually sent out all at once, when the (associate) editor has received enough reviews to make a decision. If reviewer 1 wants more X, but reviewer 2 wants less X, then it's a good thing the editor gets to see both reviews before they tell the authors which way to go. Better in any case than sending out review 1, now the authors get to work on putting more X in, only to get review 2 a month later that requires the opposite.

Comment: I much prefer reviewing for journals where you see the other reviews, there is always scope for you to learn something and improve the quality of your reviewing.

Answer (score 3):

This is decently common, but it's precisely because "what's the point if reviewers make the same comments to the authors" that reviewers don't usually see each other's reviews until *after* they submit their reviews. Sometimes the reviewer only see each other's reviews indirectly, based on what the author writes in their response to reviewers.

There are some explicit examples for one publisher [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/163920/do-mdpi-reviewers-have-access-to-each-others-reviews).