# What happen if the reviewer reject, but the editor give major revision?

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, review-articles

Dears
I submitted a paper, after 4 months I received major revisions from 2 reviewers. I made all the required amendments and submit again. One reviewer suggested to accepts it as is, the second didn't give a response. The editor sent the manuscript to a third reviewer who suggested rejection with very negative comments in everything. The editor gave us a major revision again. We have revised the manuscript again responding to all the third reviewer highlighted points (some points are not responsible for that reason we submitted a rebuttal letter to the editor before sending the revision). Do you think the editor send it again to the same reviewer? if yes: do we have a chance to be accepted? if no: can the editor resend to another reviewer or can make a final decision by himself?

Do we have a chance to be accepted in all cases?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As Buffy mentioned below, an editor can overrule a reviewer.  I was that reviewer who rejected a paper even though three other reviewers said yes.  The editor basically ignored my comments and accepted the paper.

Comment: Thank you so much for the positive answer, I am crossing my nails now, until I'll get a decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the editor send the manuscript to the same reviewer? Very likely yes. This is for a couple of reasons:

- The reviewer has already read your manuscript, so they can review again quickly.
- The reviewer had critical comments on the first paper, which the editor will (naturally) want to see addressed - or at least answered satisfactorily.

Yes your paper does have a chance to be accepted. If it didn't, you would not have gotten a major revision, but rather a rejection.

Note [the editor can choose to accept a paper even if the reviewers recommend rejection](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32397/why-do-editors-sometimes-accept-a-paper-even-if-a-reviewer-recommends-rejection). It doesn't happen often, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

An editor can overrule a reviewer. An editor can assign a paper to the same or different reviewers. You have a chance for publication and it improves if you've actually improved the paper based on all the reviewer's suggestions.

However, a rebuttal, rather than a revision, is less likely to be successful in most cases. The current situation may be different enough if your analysis is correct, but it is the editor who decides, probably with some internal consultation.

It is impossible to read the mind of the editor. I suggest you resubmit and then have some patience.

Comment: It's not even "overruling," they just get to make the decision

Comment: I will tell you right now what happened. We have made all the required changes, the editor sent back the paper to the same reviewer, he rejected it for the second time. Paper rejected definitvely.